# cURL "[skips] unknown form field" when passing semicolon-delimited string as form data

Tags: curl

#### Problem

I'm attempting to use cURL to POST form data to an API. [The API's documentation](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook) states that it accepts `multipart/form-data` content types.

Since this is part of a script, I'm trying to build a semicolon-delimited string of form fields, which is documented [here in cURL's documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F).

#### What I've Tried

What I'd *like* to be able to do (in order to easily build this string based on arguments passed to the script) is this:

```
local _payload="file=@file;username=name;content=hello"
echo "INFO payload: ${_payload}"
curl -i -F "${_payload}" "${url}"

$ ./myscript.sh <args>
# INFO payload: file=@file;username=name;content=hello  -- my script
# Warning: skip unknown form field: username=name       -- cURL
# Warning: skip unknown form field: content=hello       -- cURL
```

I get those warnings from cURL, and as expected the API never gets those values.

What *does* work is passing each field as its own argument to cURL, i.e.

```
curl -i -F "file=@file" -F "username=name" -F "content=hello" "${url}"
```

...but this isn't as nice to account for programmatically.

I should edit to mention that, in both cases, the file is received and processed properly.

#### Question

I'm certain that this is something that I'm missing, but after poring over the documentation for cURL and the API I'm requesting, I can't find it. **Why is cURL skipping these form fields**, and how can I prevent/fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a breakthrough, and of course it's right after I post my first question to Unix.SE. I re-read the docs and realized (somehow for the first time) that I'm improperly using the semicolon-delimited string.

[The docs](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F) state that the semicolon is used not to separate multiple fields, but multiple qualities of the same field. There's where I went wrong.

[The API docs](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook) state that endpoints accept a url-encoded JSON payload as a `payload_json` field, so I'm instead doing this:

```
local _json="payload_json=$(build_json)"  # defined elsewhere
local _file="file=@file"
curl -i -F "${_file}" -F "${_json}" "${url}"
```

and lo, it works. RTFD!